# How can I get the 'External name' of a SQL CLR trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sqlclr

I have created a SQL CLR trigger with the follow SQL:

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER AuditAccountsTable
   ON [dbo].[Accounts]
   FOR INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME namespace.Triggers.AuditTrigger
```

I am trying to query:

```
select * from sys.triggers
```

Is there a way to find the: `EXTERNAL NAME namespace.Triggers.AuditTrigger` on the trigger from querying in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure as I don't have a place to test this, but does the text column returned below get you close to what you're looking for?

```
select t.name, c.text
    from sys.triggers t
        inner join sys.syscomments c
            on t.object_id = c.id
    where t.type_desc = 'CLR_TRIGGER'
```

Comment: This is what I am doing now as a quick fix but if I have multiple CLR Triggers, I want to be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: I had hoped that the text column from the sys.syscomments table would contain the external name you were looking for.

Comment: @JohnEgbert and Joe: `sys.syscomments` (as well as `sys.sql_modules`) does not contain any `CREATE` statements for SQLCLR T-SQL wrapper objects. However, you can do a simple query to get this info as shown in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32171287/577765).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike T-SQL "modules" such as Stored Procedures and Functions, the SQLCLR T-SQL wrapper objects do not have their `CREATE` statements stored in the database. This is why you cannot access them via [sys.sql_modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx), [OBJECT_DEFINITION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx), or the deprecated-since-SQL-Server-2005-and-should-not-be-used [sys.syscomments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx). This is why SQLCLR Stored Procedures and Functions need to have their parameter default values stored in [sys.parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx)

Instead, `CREATE` statements for SQLCLR T-SQL wrapper objects are inferred from meta-data, just like Indexes, Primary Keys, Foreign Keys, etc.

You can get all of the parts of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement from the following query:

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.[object_id]) AS [SchemaName],
       st.[name] AS [TriggerName],
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.parent_id) AS [ParentSchemaName],
       OBJECT_NAME(st.parent_id) AS [ParentName],
       st.is_instead_of_trigger,
       SUBSTRING((
         SELECT N', ' + ste.[type_desc]
         FROM   sys.trigger_events ste
         WHERE  ste.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
         FOR XML PATH ('')
       ), 3, 500) AS [Actions],
       QUOTENAME(sa.name) AS [AssemblyName],
       QUOTENAME(sam.assembly_class) AS [AssemblyClass],
       QUOTENAME(sam.assembly_method) AS [AssemblyMethod]
FROM   sys.triggers st
INNER JOIN  sys.assembly_modules sam
        ON  sam.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
INNER JOIN  sys.assemblies sa
        ON  sa.[assembly_id] = sam.[assembly_id]
WHERE  st.parent_class = 1; --- OBJECT_OR_COLUMN
```